# what's the number of Google Calendar API limit - updating ACL

Tags: php, google-api

I was trying to add some google calendars by PHP script, and update those calendars' ACL to make it available to our whole domain users.

Everything went well except I received this error after creating bunch of calendars:

```
Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException: Expected response code 200, 
got 403 User has updated too many ACLs today. Please try again tomorrow. in
/Zend/Gdata/App.php on line 709
```

Do you guys know what exact number the limit is? That's very interesting. I tried to look at here and didn't get the answer.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar-resource/limits

Answer (score 1):

The Google Console that shows you your live quota usage lives on code.google.com: https://code.google.com/apis/console

Comment: Sorry, This might not be the answer. We're using the Google Enterprise service, so it's not listed under this link. By Oauth with domain key and secret, we're able to control all domain users' google apps, particular calendar in this case.

Comment: I use the API console to keep track of individual users API limits in a Google Apps for Education environment.  I'm surprised to hear it isn't the same in a Google Apps for Enterprise environment.